# How to load external js script in angular 2 in runtime?

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, twitter-fabric, twitter-digits

I am using Twitter digits for authentication. It needs a small .js script to be downloaded and initialize it. They recommend directly fetching the file from their server.

I have to import

`<script id="digits-sdk" src="https://cdn.digits.com/1/sdk.js" async></script>`

and initialize the sdk using like `Digits.init({})`.

I am using [angular2 webpack starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter) template which uses webpack.

Earlier I was using systemjs, where I just map the file name to the url and import it at my component. Like this

```
  var map = { 'Digits':'https://cdn.digits.com/1/sdk' };
```

then import it in angular component like `import * as Digits from 'Digits';`

I know there is webpack externals, but it is inconsistent.

`console.log(Digits)` in `ngOnInit()` sometime shows the correct object sometimes undefined error.

Answer (score 0):

I've had some luck at this.  I'm using a calendar js file and wanted to get the date result from an input to my controller.  In my case it was Pickaday.  First import the file as you normally would in whatever your main html file is.

```
<script src="/assets/js/pikaday.js"></script>
```

Then create a class the represents the functions you need.

```
export class PikadaySource {
    field: any;
    firstDay: number;
    minDate: Date;
    maxDate: Date;
    yearRange: number = 1;
    disableWeekends: boolean;
    format: string = 'MM-DD-YYYY';
    init(){};
}
```

The purpose of the class is to prevent the transpiler from having issues.  Since the imported script is in global scope it should now be usable.